# inequality involving $(xy+yz+zx)^3$ and the $pqr$ method

Tags: inequality, summation, substitution, symmetric-polynomials

For non-negative numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ the claim is that:

$$(xy+yz+zx)^3+9 x^2 y^2 z^2 \geq 4 (x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)xyz$$

Without loss of generality, one may assume that $x+y+z=1$ so that $xyz\le\frac{1}{27}$ and $xy+yz+zx\le\frac13$. I have not seen how Schur's inequality is helpful.

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: Why you have assumed $x+y+z=1$?

Comment: @SufaidSaleel If you expand both sides of the inequality, all terms are of degree 6, so if the claim is true for some triple $(x,y,z)$ then it is also true for $(ax,ay,az)$ for any constant $a$.  Therefore it is sufficient to prove the claim in the case $x+y+z=1$.

Comment: @alphacapture Got it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $xy=c$, $xz=b$ and $yz=a$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$(a+b+c)^3+9abc\geq4(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)\geq0,$$ which is Schur.